# Can I set in MariaDB the collation based on a IETF language tag?

Tags: mariadb, collation, localization

I have an application where each user account can set their preferred application language. I store those language preferences as [IETF BCP47 language tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) (e.g. "de", "en-US"). Now, for queries for that user, I want to sort the results based on their language preference.

Imagine me having the data AAA, TTT, OOO, ÖÖÖ in a table with utf8mb4_general_ci collation.

If I want them to be sorted for a German user, I can do

```
SELECT word FROM `words` order by word collate utf8mb4_german2_ci
```

Which would give me the order

> AAA, ÖÖÖ, OOO, TTT

For an Icelandic user however, using the collation `utf8mb4_icelandic_ci` I would correctly get

> AAA, OOO, TTT, ÖÖÖ

Now, in my application I don't save `utf8mb4_icelandic_ci` or `utf8mb4_german2_ci` for that user, but I save `is` or `de-DE`.

Is there a way that I can send this `is` or `de-DE` BCP47 language tag directly to MariaDB to specify the collation instead of the collation name? Or would I have to have a mapping between the language tag and the collation name in my application to send the correct collation information for the user?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(There is no direct way to do what you hypothecate.)

Build a Stored procedure that takes "de" as an argument and constructs and executes

```
SELECT word FROM `words` order by word collate utf8mb4_german2_ci
```

It would probably involve a relatively static lookup table that maps "de" and "de-DE" to "utf8mb4_german2_ci", etc.

See the docs on defining Stored Procedures and how to use `CONCAT()`, `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` in such.

Run `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';` to see which collations are available.  (It varies with the MySQL/MariaDB version.)

Comment: [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) is a short cut to the `PREPARE`/ `EXECUTE` steps.